# XSL how to remove minutes from hours

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have for example time like `19:30` and now in XSLT I want to change it to `19:00`.

The same for example from  `19:45` to `19:00`

How can I remove minutes in XSLT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(timeField, ':'), ':00')"/>
```

...where `<timeField>` contains the value you are trying to modify.